# Dificuldades em criar update com Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, orientação-a-objetos, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando criar um `update` com o Laravel 5.1 mas está trazendo o seguinte erro:

> `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::update() must be of the type array, object given`

Segue meu **Controller**

```
public function update($id)
{

                $proposta = $this->proposta;

        $proposta->cliente_id = $this->request->get('cliente_id');
        $proposta->contato = $this->request->get('contato');
        $proposta->email = $this->request->get('email');
        $proposta->telefone = $this->request->get('telefone');
        $proposta->fatcnpj = $this->request->get('fatcnpj');
        $proposta->atendimento = $this->request->get('atendimento');
        $proposta->dt_solicitacao = $this->request->get('dt_solicitacao');
        $proposta->dt_vigencia = $this->request->get('dt_vigencia');
        $proposta->vendedor = $this->request->get('vendedor');
        $proposta->coleta = $this->request->get('coleta');
        $proposta->dt_integracao = $this->request->get('dt_integracao');
        $proposta->hr_integracao = $this->request->get('hr_integracao');
        $proposta->frete_material = $this->request->get('frete_material');
        $proposta->status_id = $this->request->get('status_id');  

        $this->proposta->where('id', $id)->update($dadosForm);

        $dadosForm = $this->request->except('_token');
        $proposta_id = $id;

        $count = $this->ensaios->max('id');


        for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++){ //Save Ensaios

        $proposta_ensaios = new PropostaEnsaios();

        $proposta_ensaios->id_proposta = $proposta_id;
        $proposta_ensaios->id_produto = $i;
        $proposta_ensaios->quantidade = $dadosForm['quantidade_'.$i];
        $proposta_ensaios->valor= $dadosForm['valor_'.$i];
        $proposta_ensaios->total = $dadosForm['total_'.$i];

        $proposta_ensaios->where('id', $id)->update($dadosForm);
}
```

Comment: em qual dos dois updates exatamente acontece isso?

Comment: Não é só dar um save? em `$proposta->save()` ????

Comment: @NeuberOliveira no Primeiro mas o segundo está igual vai acontecer a mesma coisa

Comment: @VirgilioNovic o $proposta->save() ele tentar dar um insert e não um update

Comment: @ShaolinFantastic ai tem por menores, eu consigo mesmo sento instância nova fazer com que ela faça update em vez de insert, claro que eu entendo o que você disse porque eu faria totalmente diferente trazendo a instância direto da pesquisa com um `find(1)` e depois alterava, então o seu código só precisa ser arrumado para solucionar o seu problema é que peço desculpa eu não achei o fil da meada !

Comment: Exemplo aqui eu faria: `$proposta = $this->proposta->find(1);`; já está em modo de update alterando os campos e dando um `$proposta->save();` acredito que resolva essa parte do problema! @ShaolinFantastic

Comment: @VirgilioNovic acredito que o update funciona por que o `$id` acaba sendo `null`, ai quando chega na banco, provavelmente o id é auto increment, ai quando recebe nulo continua a sequencia

Comment: @NeuberOliveira não entendi o que você acabou de escrever como comentário.

Comment: Uma coisa que pode funcionar tambem, faz um tempinho que nao mexo com laravel, já que esta populando o objeto antes, tenta assim, `$this->proposta->where('id', $id)->update()`

Answer (score 2):

O parametro do update precisa ser um array `chave=>valor` por isso esta dando o erro.

O segundo update provavelmente vai funcionar por que o `$this->request->except('_token');` vai retorna um array `chave=>valor` com execao do campo `_token`.

Mas voltando a duvida acho qeu o certo seria algo mais desse tipo

```
$dadosPropostaForm = $this->request->except('_token');
$this->proposta->where('id', $id)->update($dadosPropostaForm);
```

No for que salva os ensasios precisa tambem de um array `chave=>valor`

```
$proposta_ensaios = new PropostaEnsaios();

$proposta_ensaios_dados['id_proposta'] = $proposta_id;
$proposta_ensaios_dados['id_produto'] = $i;
$proposta_ensaios_dados['quantidade'] = $dadosForm['quantidade_'.$i];
$proposta_ensaios_dados['valor']= $dadosForm['valor_'.$i];
$proposta_ensaios_dados['total'] = $dadosForm['total_'.$i];

$proposta_ensaios->where('id', $id)->update($proposta_ensaios_dados);
```

Comment: Só uma duvida nesse exemplo teria que alterar meu Model?

Comment: nao, o problema é que o update recebe um array como parametro e nao um objeto. Como disse o request vai retornar um array, e nos ensaios apenas formatei os dados como um array

Comment: Nao deu certo aparece o mesmo erro do começo Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::update() must be of the type array, null given, called

Comment: verifica o que esta vindo em `$dadosPropostaForm` o que acontece agora é que por algum motivo esta indo `null` no parametro do `update()`.

Comment: Nao deu certo tentei desta forma mas nao funcionou